# nodemailer attachment is not working

Tags: node.js, attachment, ubuntu-16.04, nodemailer

i want to attach zip file. but it doesn't work any attachment.

here is my source code.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var fs = require('fs');
var mailinfo = require('../config/mail_info').info;

var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: mailinfo.host,
    port: mailinfo.port,
    auth: mailinfo.auth,
    tls: mailinfo.tls,
    debug: true,
});

router.post('/',function(req,res){
    var emailsendee = req.body.emailAddress;
    console.log(emailsendee);
    var emailsubject = "Requested File";
    var emailText = "test";
    var emailFrom = 'test@test.com';

    var mailOptions={
        from : "test <test@test.com>",
        to : emailsendee,
        subject : emailsubject,
        html : '<h1>' + emailText+ '</h1>';
        attachments : [
             {
                filename : '',//i just put black make you understand esaily
                path : ''//what i did is under this code
             }
         ]
     };

     console.log(mailOptions);
     smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
     if(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.end();
     }else{
         console.log(response);
         res.end();
     } 
 }); 
 });

 module.exports = router;
```

i tried these for attaching a file

```
enter code here
attachments:[{ fileName: 'test.log', streamSource: fs.createReadStream('./test.log'}]
```

it still sends a mail without attachment.
when this code can't read a file there is a error.
so i guess this isn't working because of reading a file.
and i read some questions on stackoverflow which has similar error with me.

i fixed path -> filepath
and fixed streamSource -> path
my nodemailer version is 4.0.1.
help me send a mail with zip file.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using exactly the same version of [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/)(**4.0.1** at this moment) and I'm sending emails with attachments successfully.

Your first code snippet looks promising :)

But the second part

> i tried these for attaching a file

> attachments:[{ **fileName**: 'test.log', **streamSource**: fs.createReadStream('./test.log'}]

doesn't look right at all ...

Please refer to [**nodemailer docs**](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-attachments/)

**fileName** and **streamSource** are not a valid parameters of ***mailOptions*** object

**EXAMPLE FROM DOCS**

```
var mailOptions = {
    ...
    attachments: [
        {   // utf-8 string as an attachment
            filename: 'text1.txt',
            content: 'hello world!'
        },
        {   // binary buffer as an attachment
            filename: 'text2.txt',
            content: new Buffer('hello world!','utf-8')
        },
        {   // file on disk as an attachment
            filename: 'text3.txt',
            path: '/path/to/file.txt' // stream this file
        },
        {   // filename and content type is derived from path
            path: '/path/to/file.txt'
        },
        {   // stream as an attachment
            filename: 'text4.txt',
            content: fs.createReadStream('file.txt')
        },
        {   // define custom content type for the attachment
            filename: 'text.bin',
            content: 'hello world!',
            contentType: 'text/plain'
        },
        {   // use URL as an attachment
            filename: 'license.txt',
            path: 'https://raw.github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/master/LICENSE'
        },
        {   // encoded string as an attachment
            filename: 'text1.txt',
            content: 'aGVsbG8gd29ybGQh',
            encoding: 'base64'
        },
        {   // data uri as an attachment
            path: 'data:text/plain;base64,aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ='
        },
        {
            // use pregenerated MIME node
            raw: 'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n' +
                 'Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n' +
                 '\r\n' +
                 'Hello world!'
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see you should change **fileName** to **filename** and **streamSource** to **content**

```
// WRONG
attachments:[{ fileName: 'test.log', streamSource: fs.createReadStream('./test.log'}]

// RIGHT
attachments:[{ filename: 'test.log', content: fs.createReadStream('./test.log'}]
```

Good Luck! I hope this was helpful for you :)

Comment: Working like charm. TQ :)